# Why Does PGFPLOTs not work in Beamer article class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am writing a masters thesis and have many graphs built using PGFPLOTs TIKZ and CSV data files. These graphs work perfectly fine when my document class is article; however, when I try to switch my document class to beamer to create a presentation the code will not compile.

My main problem seems to be the following error:

Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '"Bird Beak T-specimen Compression Data"' in 'search path=.'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your end-of-lines? Try `row sep=crcr' and terminate your lines with` \' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details)

I have tried to add 'row sep=crcr' and add \ to the end of each line, but it does not solve the issue. Since this code works when the document class is article it is clear that Beamer is the issue

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately we don't have a crystal ball. Until then it would be beneficial, if you'd prepare two sets of minimal code, which: a) we can copy&run, b) works with article but fails with beamer.

Comment: Well almost immediately after posting I realized that my search path for the CSV data was wrong, I fixed that and got rid of the error shown above. Now I have a different compile error. I will post the error and the code.

Comment: I am having trouble trying to input 'Bird Beak T-specimen Graph.tex' at the following link:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/qbwwwysqcgdv

Error 1: Runaway argument? next to \begin{wrap figure}
Error 2: Missing \endgroup inserted
Missing } inserted

this plot worked in my thesis just fine, just cannot get it to work in beamer

Comment: Fine. // May I ask you to stop here? Unlike other places we tend to a) avoid chit-chat, and b) provide 1 question (=problem) only: then each answer can present 1 solution. to 1 problem So I suggest to close this one, and to open a new question about the compile error.

Comment: Ok, no problem MS-SPO. Not really sure what the problem is, so posting one error at a time will likely result in 10 posts and a project that still doesn't compile. Any recommendations for how to tackle the issue?

Comment: "one at a time" is the only viable way with LaTeX (and friends). Often the first error generates cascades of errors, and almost always they make no sense after the first one is corrected. So do as @MS-SPO suggests: prepare a minimal example that shows the first error, post a question, correct it, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Ok, I will close this question and start a new one. Thank you all.